# Spark k-means OutOfMemoryError

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, cluster-analysis

I am using spark's k-means clustering under Ml module and I am programming in PySpark. The module works well until 200 clusters but it gives `OutOfMemoryError` once I go past 300 clusters and more. My
data contains 200k objects and 25k features for each object. I am following the guidelines mentioned under the `class pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans` from the link [pyspark ML mocumentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=kmeans#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans). The only difference between the code mentioned in this documentation and mine is that I am using sparse vectors instead of dense.

There is no hardware limitation since I am having a resonably large cluster setup which has over 700 cores and 2TB memory. I searched for this problem and most of the links lead me to do one/all of the following configurations.
The following are the set of things that I tried:

- set/increase driver memory using `conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "64g")`
- set parallelism `conf.set("spark.default.parallelism","1000")`
- set/increase memory fraction `conf.set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")`

In addition to the above configuration I set the *executor memory as 16g* and *cores as 150*.Unfortunately nothing has worked out and I keep getting the following error (error truncated).

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.fit. :
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector.toArray(Vectors.scala:678)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.VectorWithNorm.toDense(KMeans.scala:612)

Does this mean spark cannot handle even a `200k*25K` dataset for 300+  cluster size?, or am I missing something?.

Comment: Benchmark a **non-distributed tool** such as ELKI in comparison. Usually, it will perform surprisingly well as long as the data fits into main memory. 200k objects is not that much, that should still work on a single host. In my experience, distributed "stuff" is surprisingly slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.VectorWithNorm.toDense(KMeans.scala:612)
```

That's the problem. The cluster centres are converted to a dense representation, and then broadcasted to all the executors. This will not scale with thousands of features, which is your case. Checkout [SparseML](https://github.com/intel-analytics/SparseML).

Comment: Nice link to `SparseML`. Have you used it?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will use it and see if it works out for me.